# What is the meaning of the structure constant for the $\rm SU(3)$ group and how I can find its values?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, feynman-diagrams, higgs, quantum-chromodynamics, lie-algebra

To calculate the tree-level amplitude for:

$$Z(p_1) + Z(p_2) \to Z(p_3) +Z(p_4)$$

I must take into the consideration, amongst other cases, the amplitude for:

[image]

I know the values shown in another post for the structure constants (f) exist, [$\mathfrak{su}(3)$ structure constants](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428066/), but I don't understand what these numbers mean. How do the particles being a Z or W boson change such values?

Is this related to longitudinal polarization vectors in any way?

How are these values used to find the amplitude of a diagram?

Comment: You can find all the SU(3) structure constants directly on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants

Comment: I have read that article, but I don't understand how this can be used to calculate the tree-level amplitude of , for example, the 4-boson vertex above.....thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah I must have misread, what is the actual issue though, are you having a problem drawing the appropriate diagrams and applying the electroweak Feynman rules? If you look at this resource the 4 boson vertex is a lot simpler https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9783527648887.app2

Comment: once again thank you for your help. I have seen that article before, but I don't understand how they went from the formula I mentioned above to the shorter ones presented in Figure B.4 as an example. How did the author know the correct $f_{abc}$ values to get the shortened formulas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the values for the structure constants ($f^{abc}$) of a gauge group?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536463/)

Comment: I know that the different casimir's give us different values but what I don't understand is, how do I know for example if $f^{abc }= f^{123}$ or equal to $f^{147}$?

Comment: This is similar to asking how do you know whether $g^{\alpha\gamma}$ is $g^{00}$ or $g^{12}$. The final answer should have no free indices.